# Why the links in the footer are not working?

Tags: html, web

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 footer-social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ooty.heritage.92><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/OotyAnd><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ooty_heritage/?hl=en><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/110334609097832679127"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ooty-heritage-tours-and-travels-81065a170/><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</div>
```

Here i face a very big problem with the footer the links dont work even after everything seems to be correct. Can anyone suggest me to do anything. A very simple place giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: You're missing the closing quotes.

Answer (score 1):

quotes are missing href=""

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 footer-social">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ooty.heritage.92"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/OotyAnd"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ooty_heritage/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/110334609097832679127"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ooty-heritage-tours-and-travels-81065a170/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct href like this

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 footer-social">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ooty.heritage.92"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/OotyAnd"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ooty_heritage/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/110334609097832679127"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ooty-heritage-tours-and-travels-81065a170"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </div>
```